# DOMNodeList find php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Объясните мне, почему не хочет работать find() в domDocument'e?
Пробую делать так:

```
// создаю новый объект класса
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// получаю контент
@$dom->loadHTML($my_html);

// убираю пробелы
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// извлекаю все теги ссылок
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->find('a');
```

На выходе ошибка

> Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::find()

Comment: А с чего вы вообще взяли, что метод `DOMNodeList::find` существует? [Оф. документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domnodelist.php) такого метода не знает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP правильно сообщает вам, что класс [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domnodelist.php) не имеет метода `find`.

Если вы хотите получать все ссылки, находящиеся в таблицах, то можно использовать специальный [XPath](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) запрос. Например так:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($my_html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('*/table//a');
```

А вот и [работающий пример](http://ideone.com/HSvgHo) на IDE One.

Comment: Почему-то ничего не выводится. У меня не `xml` формат кода, а `html`.

Comment: Ошибок правда нет.

Comment: Код, что я привел в ответе работает. Добавил пруф в сам ответ. Скорее всего, проблемы с вашей разметкой. Есть чувство, что она не валидна. Ну и в вашем вопросе есть злой символ `@`, который **никогда** не стоит использовать в PHP.